# mousemover listener disables click listener in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, event-listener

My end goal is to allow the user of my app to draw a single line on a Google map, to find the direction (azimuth or heading) of that line.

I want the user to be able to draw one and only one line, at which point a further function is called to return the direction of the line. The POLYLINE option in the Drawing Manager requires a double click to end the line and that is not what I want.

The code below ([contained in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hominator74/7coqd7uo/13/)) works inasmuch as it accepts clicks for a start and an end point, and then draws the line. However, I would like to draw the line from the start point to current mouse position before the second click occurs, so that the user can see the line before finalizing it. If I uncomment this line (line 39 in the JS):

`if (lineDrawActive == 1) { drawLine(startPt.latLng, currentPt.latLng); }`

then the line is drawn, but then ***the click listener doesn't work anymore and I cannot end the line***.

I am looking to understand why this second click *does* get heard if line 39 is commented out, but *doesn't* get heard if that line is present.

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Map Practice</title>

<style>
    html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

</style>

<script>

var azimuthLine;

function loadMap() {

    var myLatlng = {lat: 37.78, lng: -122.44};

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng
      });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('linedraw'), 'click', function() {
        var lineDrawActive = 0;
        var startPt, endPt;

        if(azimuthLine != undefined) { azimuthLine.setMap(null) }; //if a line exists, delete it

        //log the coordinates when the user makes a first click on the map
        var listener1 = map.addListener('click', function(clickPt) {
            if(lineDrawActive == 0) {
                console.log('First click'); //alert user that the first click has been detected
                lineDrawActive = 1; 
                console.dir('Start: '+clickPt.latLng.lat()+', '+clickPt.latLng.lng());
                startPt = clickPt;

            } else {
                console.log('Second click'); //alert user that the click has been detected
                endPt = clickPt;
                lineDrawActive = 0;
                console.dir('Stop: '+clickPt.latLng.lat()+', '+clickPt.latLng.lng());
                google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
                google.maps.event.removeListener(listener2);
                drawLine(startPt.latLng, endPt.latLng);
            }
        });
        var listener2 = map.addListener('mousemove', function(currentPt) {
            console.log('Mouse moved');
            document.getElementById('azimuth').innerHTML = currentPt.latLng;
            if (lineDrawActive == 1) {
                drawLine(startPt.latLng, currentPt.latLng);
            }
        });
    });
}

function drawLine(startPt, endPt) {
    if(azimuthLine != undefined) { azimuthLine.setMap(null) }; //if a line exists, delete it
    var azimuthCoordinates = [startPt,endPt];
    azimuthLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: azimuthCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    azimuthLine.setMap(map);
}


</script>

<!-- Google maps API -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCpvhh2O7Kv-wJfcB88JaVzDLUgs1WNrv8&callback=loadMap&libraries=geometry,drawing"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<button id="linedraw">Start</button>

<span id="azimuth">0</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mouse is over the polyline, which is absorbing the clicks.  Set the polyline to `clickable: false` and it works (at least as I expect).

```
function drawLine(startPt, endPt) {
    if(azimuthLine != undefined) { azimuthLine.setMap(null) };
    var azimuthCoordinates = [startPt,endPt];
    azimuthLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: azimuthCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        clickable: false  // ********************** add this
    });
    azimuthLine.setMap(map);
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7coqd7uo/14/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var azimuthLine;

function initMap() {

  var myLatlng = {
    lat: 37.78,
    lng: -122.44
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('linedraw'), 'click', function() {
    var lineDrawActive = 0;
    var startPt, endPt;

    if (azimuthLine != undefined) {
      azimuthLine.setMap(null)
    };

    //log the coordinates when the user makes a first click on the map
    var listener1 = map.addListener('click', function(clickPt) {
      console.log("click:" + clickPt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
      if (lineDrawActive == 0) {
        console.log('First click'); //alert user that the first click has been detected
        lineDrawActive = 1;
        console.dir('Start: ' + clickPt.latLng.lat() + ', ' + clickPt.latLng.lng());
        startPt = clickPt;

      } else {
        console.log('Second click'); //alert user that the click has been detected
        endPt = clickPt;
        lineDrawActive = 0;
        console.dir('Stop: ' + clickPt.latLng.lat() + ', ' + clickPt.latLng.lng());
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener2);
        drawLine(startPt.latLng, endPt.latLng);
      }
    });
    var listener2 = map.addListener('mousemove', function(currentPt) {
      console.log('Mouse moved');
      document.getElementById('azimuth').innerHTML = currentPt.latLng;
      if (lineDrawActive == 1) {
        drawLine(startPt.latLng, currentPt.latLng);
      }
    });
  });
}

function drawLine(startPt, endPt) {
  if (azimuthLine != undefined) {
    azimuthLine.setMap(null)
  };
  var azimuthCoordinates = [startPt, endPt];
  azimuthLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: azimuthCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    clickable: false
  });
  azimuthLine.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<button id="linedraw">Start</button>

<span id="azimuth">0</span>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: That's it!! Brilliant, I would never have figured that out but it makes perfect sense. And now works exactly as I want it. Thanks so much!